# HTML Node tree with add buttons and hierarchical numbering

Tags: javascript, parsing, tree

How to create a JavaScript based tree where you have add buttons, to add extra child elements.

For example, it has to look like this:

[image: Picture how it need to look]

I need do be able to add child elements, and I need to make number counting work like that also.

I tried jQuery `click()` and then added `append()`, but it didn't come out as I expected. It started randomly adding rows.

Is there a simple way to do this or am I just overthinking this too much? I'm new in coding and any help would be appreciated.

I started like below, but obviously it's not working like that:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('#parent').on('click', function() {
    $('#tree').append('<li><input type="text"></li>')
    $('#tree li:last').append('<button type="button" id="child">ADD</button>')
    $('#tree li:last').append('<ul></ul>')

    $('#child').on('click', function() {
      $('#tree li ul').append('<li><input type="text"></li>')
      $('#tree li ul li:last ').append('<button id="child2" type="button">ADD</button>')
      $('#tree li ul li:last').append('<ul></ul>')

      $('#child2').on('click', function() {
        $('#tree li ul li ul').append('<li><input type="text"></li>')
        $('#tree li ul li ul li:last').append('<button id="child3" type="button">ADD</button>')
        $('#tree li ul li ul li:last').append('<ul></ul>')

        $('#child3').on('click', function() {
          $('#tree li ul li ul li ul').append('<li><input type="text"></li>')
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="tree"><button type="button" id="parent">ADD</button></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the code you tried that you have problems with, otherwise we cannot help you fixing it.

Comment: Where in your code did you attempt to write "node 1.1.1" like in the image? Instead I see `input` elements, which is quite different from the image... Please clarify.

Comment: @trincot i started with using input elements because just for experimenting, i tried to find logic that could work

Comment: But surely you can output "node 1.1.1", ... have you really no attempt at that? We appreciate questions that show effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code repetition that you have is indeed a problem. You cannot do this indefinitely.

The solution is to create a generic click handler which will capture a click on any button that exists now or in some future.

For the nested numbering, you can use the [`counters()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counters()) CSS-function.

As you are using jQuery, I would also suggest to rely more on the methods it provides:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#tree').on('click', 'button', function() {
        $(this).before(
            $("<li>").append(
                $("<ul>").append(
                    $("<button>").text("Add")
                )
            )
        );
    });
});
```

```css
ul { counter-reset: item }
li { display: block }
li:before { 
    content: "node " counters(item, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: item 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><ul id="tree"><button id="parent">Add</button></ul></div>
```

This shows more "Add" buttons than in your image, as there are more places where content can be inserted. Every click on such a button will result in one more button.

Comment: thank you a lot, as i sayed im new in this and this is also my first task in coding, I didnt know about counters option in css :)